# Parse Swift Login Error: Invalid User Credentials

Tags: ios, swift, authentication, parse-platform

I am trying to log in to Parse with an existing user/password of myname/mypass but I keep getting Error Code 101, Invalid Login Credentials.

I know myname/mypass works because I was able to use the signUp function to create this user and get into the app as usual. I am also able to see the existence of this user on the Parse web interface.

I have tried pulling username/password from text fields and also hardcoding in "myname"/"mypass". Everything yields the same.

```
 @IBAction func loginButtonTapped(sender: AnyObject) {
        println(userNameTextField.text) //correctly prints the string.
        println(passwordTextField.text) //correctly prints the string.
        PFUser.logInWithUsernameInBackground(userNameTextField.text, password:passwordTextField.text) {
            (user: PFUser?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
            if user != nil {
                var currentUser = PFUser.currentuser()
                println("log in succesful") // this does not print.
                performSegueWithIdentifier("SegueToHomeScreen", self) // this does not happen
            } else {
                // The login failed. Check error to see why.
            }
        }
```

I know this is similar to a few other questions on SO, but those have been unanswered. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: As a note, I can confirm that the user exists: I queried for the user with options on  `PFUser.query()` and returned the correct user. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ugh, I feel like an idiot. I'd like to thank the others for their suggestions, when it fact it was my own failure.

I was (shamefully) hardcoding the password as a string "myPassword" during signUp, so I thought I was signing up with password "pass" and "myPassword" was being sent. I didn't focus on the signUpViewController since it was working fine.

Don't be like me. Before you go any further, make sure you are setting your username and pass as intended in your signUp.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried forcing the PFUser to unwrap by doing `(user: PFUser!, error: NSError?)` instead of `(user: PFUser?, error: NSError?)`. This is the only difference I can see when comparing your code to the official guide [here](https://parse.com/docs/ios/guide#users-logging-in).

Comment: Thanks for the thought. I did try that, but then I get "Cannot invoke loginWithUsernameInBackground with an argument list of type '(String!, password: String!, (PFUser!, NSError?) -> Void)'" Any thoughts?

Comment: Basically your user is a nil variable, have you tried instantiating a `PFUser` further up in the class?

Comment: I really do appreciate your interest in this. I instantiated further up in the function with `var user = PFUser()`, but if I set `user.logInWithUsernameInBackground...` I get "PFUser does not have a member named logInWithUsernameInBackground."