# Login Parse Server Error code 101: Invalid Username/Password

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, parse-server

When I go to log a user in, I get the error message: `[Error]: Invalid username/password. (Code: 101, Version: 1.12.0)`. The user exists, is shown in Parse Dashboard, and I can sign up just fine. I've done research on this topic and I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30076772/parse-swift-login-error-invalid-user-credentials), but it doesn't appear to work both on a real device and the simulator.

Xcode: 7.3
iOS: 9.3

My code is below:

```
  PFUser.logInWithUsernameInBackground((usernameField?.text)!, password: (passwordField?.text)!) { (user: PFUser?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
            if error == nil {
                //Segue to account
                self.defaults.data.setValue(self.usernameField?.text, forKey: "currentUser")

               self.presentViewController(AccountInterface(), animated: true, completion: {

               })
            } else {
                print(error?.description)
            }
        }
```

Thanks

Comment: Any app that remain on Parse as of April 28 will be marked as low priority. But I was using Parse up to a few days ago and I noticed that things really started to slow down and it affect my app a lot. Specifically it affected my sign up. Once a user signed up, it took like 20 min before that user could updat any of their table properties. So it is possible that this is just Parse winding things down and somehow it is affecting your code. Doubtful but possible. Either way I would highly recommend not using parse, instead try Firebase, its pretty cool. Not quite as simple, but simple enough

Comment: @MikeG I am migrated to Parse Server, but thanks for the suggestion.